# Modal Form Submit Button Not Working When Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a modal dropdown form with four dropdown lists, with the fourth dropdown containing a link to a document to display once user clicks the submit button. All four dropdowns work fine, however when clicking the submit button the document does not display. The form simply continues to display. Any help is appreciated.

```
        var selectedOptions = {};

        $('#link1').on('change', function () {
            var a = $(this).val();
            selectedOptions['1'] = a;
            selectedOptions['2'] = a;
            selectedOptions['3'] = a;
            if (a !== '') {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSecondSelect[a].length; i++) {
                    $('#link2').append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", dataSecondSelect[a][i])
                            .text(dataSecondSelect[a][i]));
                }
            }
        });

        $('#link2').on('change', function () {
            var a = $(this).val();
            selectedOptions['1'] = a;
            selectedOptions['2'] = a;
            selectedOptions['3'] = a;
            if (a !== '') {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataThirdSelect[a].length; i++) {
                    $('#link3').append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", dataThirdSelect[a][i])
                            .text(dataThirdSelect[a][i]));
                }
            }
        });
        $('#link3').on('change', function () {
            var a = $(this).val();
            selectedOptions['1'] = a;
            selectedOptions['2'] = a;
            selectedOptions['3'] = a;
            if (a !== '') {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataFourthSelect[a].length; i++) {
                    $('#link4').append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", dataFourthSelect[a][i].link)
                            .text(dataFourthSelect[a][i].form));
                }
            }
        });

    $('#clickButton').on('click', function () {
        var error = false;
        $(".error").remove();
        $(".validation-error").removeClass('validation-error');
        $('#myModal select').each(function () {
            // validate first
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                var _message = "Please select an option";
                $(this).addClass('validation-error');
                $(this).after($('<div class="error"></div>').text(_message));
                error=true;
            }
        });

        if (error) { return; }
        // form is now validated so get the link
        var _index = $("#link4").val();
        var _form = dataFourthSelect[_index][0].link;
        resetForm($(this)[0]);
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        openDoc(_form);

    });

    function resetForm(e) {
        $(".error").remove();
        $(".validation-error").removeClass('validation-error');
        e.form.reset();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the logs or console? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: The logs indicate 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'.

Comment: couple places that error could be coming from.  var _form = dataFourthSelect[_index][0].link; resetForm($(this)[0]); try console logging $(this) and  _index. see if either of those is undefined

Answer (score 0):

while going through your given code, i noticed the `#link4` does not exists.

so the line `var _index = $("#link4").val();` will return `undefined` which will subsequently fails the following line of code

```
var _form = dataFourthSelect[_index][0].link;
```

hope this helps.